# Need insight on understanding this small piece of HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, linkedin-api

I've embedded a LinkedIn Apply Now button on [my page](http://students.sabanciuniv.edu/dmurat/linkedin_widget/linkedin_apply_now.html). But there are several things that confuse me. First of all, when I right click the widget, I cannot "save as" the image. Guess because it's not an image! How is such a button created?

Secondly, when I right click the page and view source, all I see is the code I have written. I thought the `in.js` that is included would append DOM elements to the document in order to make that button visible. (e.g `headElement.appendChild(document.createElement('img'))` or something like that. How come? If nothing is embedded into the DOM tree, how is that button there? If somethings are embedded, then why aren't they visible in the HTML source code? Because when I `headElement.appendChild` something by using Javascript, it appears in the HTML source as well.

And last but not least, how can I check if that LinkedIn button is standing there in an iframe or by itself?

**EDIT:** I inspected the element on Chrome and what I get is a bunch of `span` tags. There is also an `a` tag with `href="javascript:void(0);`. What's that supposed to mean? What does `javascript:void(0)` do?

I would appreciate some deep insight into this as I am pretty new to front-end development, html and javascript and all...

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The button is nothing more than a few nested `span`s, one of which, with id = `li_ui_li_gen_1325073350899_0-logo` is styled with CSS to have a background image, pointing to http://static02.linkedin.com/scds/common/u/img/sprite/sprite_connect_v13.png

Note that that image contains other things aside from the background of the button. That is because they are using a technique called [CSS sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites).

Indeed much of the work is done by the in.js file. If you look through the code, however, you'll see that it has been minified, so it is a bit though (but not at all impossible, it is actually a good exercise) to go through the code.

Finally, no, there is no `iframe`, just a bunch of `span`s.

As the other answer says, you can try using FF+Firebug or Chrome to explore the document.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to really see the html that was inserted by the linkedin code is to use a browser like Safari or Chrome (or Firefox with Firebug) and right-click the button and choose Inspect Element. This will give you a nice view of the DOM and what the script actually did to your document. View Source doesn't give you this by default.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, it's not an image. It's made up of several nested spans and an anchor with various CSS styles applied. (There may be a background image included somewhere in the CSS, but you can't right-click to save background images set with CSS.)

Secondly, View Source only shows the source as sent by the web server. Any subsequent changes made through script will not be reflected.

You can use the developer tools from the browser of your choice (Chrome has it built in, for example, or get Firebug for Firefox) to view the current DOM, which will also answer your last question. In Chrome you can right-click and choose Inspect Element to open the developer stuff up with that element pre-selected.

EDIT for the question edit: `href="javascript:void(0);"` What's that supposed to mean?

An `href` that has `javascript: somecode` will execute whatever `somecode` is instead of navigating to a url like for a "normal" `href`. The [`void` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) basically evaluates the associated expression and then returns undefined, so `void(0)` doesn't do anything. Putting that together, `href="javascript:void(0);"` basically says "instead of navigating somewhere, do nothing", but the anchor tag still has the other behaviour of a "normal" anchor in terms of appearance, being a tabstop, etc. Normally where you see such a setting there will also be an `onclick` event handler with some JavaScript to do something else (which may or may not involve navigation) when the user clicks the anchor.

Many consider this a bad practice because if the user has JavaScript turned off the anchor tag won't do anything at all. It's generally better to leave the `href` with a url that is the equivalent of whatever the click event handler does, albeit typically a less fancy version. Then the click handler will cancel the default action for the click so that the default navigation to that url won't occur and instead something else will happen (perhaps an Ajax call). That way most users will see the fancier behaviour, but users with JavaScript disabled can still use the link.

Answer (score 1):

I gave the button a quick look, here I few points

1. Uses CSS properties like border radious, gradients,border top etc to give finish to the button
2. Image Sprites are being used for linkdin logo in right of the button: http://static02.linkedin.com/scds/common/u/img/sprite/sprite_connect_v13.png
3. Lastly, I didn't detect any javascript as far as styling of this button is concerned

If I missed something, just let me know :)